# To get Schengen visa can my arrival and departure countries be different?

Tags: visas, schengen

Can I get a schengen visa if my arrival and departure countries are different? Will my plane ticket be accepted in that scenario?

Comment: It is quite common to travel out of an other Schengen country, but to help you best, we should have more details, like your nationality and your proposed countries of travel.

Comment: i from Bangladesh and iam trying say that, i will arrive at France and departure from italy. if i show those airline ticket, are they will approve those document???

Comment: As Willeke wrote, that shouldn't be a problem. What is most important in that regard is that you apply at the embassy of the country that will be your main destination (if there is one, otherwise you apply at the embassy of the country of arrival).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must I enter Europe with Schengen visa from the country where I applied?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/must-i-enter-europe-with-schengen-visa-from-the-country-where-i-applied)

Comment: @blackbird57 The OP does not (yet) have a visa and is wondering about the application, the other question is about what you are allowed to do once you have a visa. It really isn't suited as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal to stay in several Schengen countries and arrive/depart from different countries, the Schengen area has been created to make things like that easier. You don't need to worry about the plane tickets *per se* but you do need to present a coherent itinerary. Explain why you want to go to both countries, what you will do there (with evidence like invitation, bookings, etc. as applicable) and [make sure to apply to the right country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43258/least-strict-schengen-visa-application-france-or-italy/43262#43262).

Comment: but their requirement to apply for Schengen visa, is they want the return ticket of the airline im traveling. so if i show that my return ticket is from a different country then are they will agree to approve the visa proposal??

Comment: @Hasan Yes, that is OK, if you follow the rules for which country you should apply to.

Comment: @Hasan In principle, what they want above all is evidence you will leave the Schengen area in time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You file the planned itinerary with your visa application, and that itinerary has to make sense. It doesn't have to enter and leave through the same country.