# Schengen Visa Application Travel

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, europe, netherlands, amsterdam

Can I issue my tourist Schengen visa for the Netherlands from Country A even though my plane tickets are booked from another country (Country B) to Amsterdam?

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few questions on this site about that already, looking for a duplicate now. This question is not a duplicate of your question but its answer addresses your question as well: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/must-i-enter-europe-with-schengen-visa-from-the-country-where-i-applied I can not find a true duplicate now, will write an answer later if nobody else finds one.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Note however that the place you apply for a visa from should usually be your place of residence. The exact rules vary by destination country and sometimes locally, check your consulate’s website for details. The place you are arriving from is irrelevant, though we have seen cases of the Schengen consulate asking for proof that you have the relevant visa for that country (even if that makes no sense). It is more common for the place you will be leaving/returning to.

Comment: My place of residence is Turkiye and which is where I plan to travel from, however, I want to apply for the Schengen from my country of origin. So technically, I do not visa for either of the two countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your visa application would describe your itinerary. If there is a reasonable explanation why you travel from B, there is absolutely no problem to travel from B. Even if you later change things so that you travel from B there should be no problem since it is a good *rule of thumb* to apply for visa in reverse order, so that with each application you can explain when and where you will leave again.